# Coverage test tool on Mac OS X?

Tags: python, macos, testing

I searched in the network there are some like Rational purecoverage; Numega Turecoverage; Telelogic Logicscope.

Can you tell me which tool can be used on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 0):

How about [coverage](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/coverage)?  I don't see an OSX installer, so install it using *pip* or *easy_install*.  It has a C module (optional, I think) which will need to be compiled for OSX, but if you have a compiler installed *pip* or *easy_install* should handle it.